# C# Populating a treeview from database results

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am learning the C# programming language and am making a payroll application add-on for SAP business One. I have never used a treeview before and wanted to know how one goes about populating the tree items from a database. I am using Visual Studio 2010 and Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

I have one parent with 2 children, i.e.

```
- Component                        ....Parent
      Earnings                     ....child
      Deductions                   ....child
```

I want the Earnings child to show all results from a U_PD_description field where U_PD_type = "Earnings", i.e

```
- Component                        ....Parent
          Earnings                     ....child
              Housing Allowance
              Mobile Phone Allowance
              Mileage Allowance
          Deductions                   ....child
```

and likewise for deductions. I have the following code for formload:

```
 private void frm_earn_deduct_setup_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get service instance
            var earnDeductMasterService = Program.Kernel.Get<IEarnDeductMasterService>();

            //Query database for all records that have earnings
            var earnings = from ed in earnDeductMasterService.GetAllEarnDeductMasters()
                           where ed.U_PD_type.Trim().Equals("Earnings".Trim(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                           select ed;

            if (earnings.Any(x => x != null))
            {
                //To populate subtree Earnings with U_PD_description results
                //.....some code here
            }
            else 
            {
                //Nothing to populate            
            }

            //.............................................................................
            //Query database for all records that have deductions
            var deductions = from ed in earnDeductMasterService.GetAllEarnDeductMasters()
                             where ed.U_PD_type.Trim().Equals("Deductions".Trim(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                             select ed;

            if (deductions.Any(x => x != null))
            {
                //To populate subtree Deductions with U_PD_description results
                //.....some code here
            }
            else
            {
                //Nothing to populate            
            }

            // Disable default items
            txt_amt_greater_than.Enabled = false; 
            bindingNavigatorDeleteItem.Enabled = false;

            // Call service instance
            earnDeductMasterBindingSource.DataSource = Program.Kernel.Get<IEarnDeductMasterService>().GetAllEarnDeductMasters().ToList();
        }
```

Can anyone show me an example on how to populate say the earnings subtree in treeView1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood correctly what you want, then here is example how to populate treeview:

```
List<string> earnings = new List<string>() { "Housing Allowance", "Mobile Phone Allowance", "Mileage Allowance" };
List<string> deductions = new List<string>() { "Housing Ban", "Mobile Phone Ban", "Mileage Ban" };

treeView1.Nodes.Add("Component");//adding root node
treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("Earnings");//adding earnings child node
treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("Deductions");//adding deduction child node

//adding all earnings to "Earnings" node
foreach (string earning in earnings)
{
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(earning);
}

//adding all deductions to "Deductions" node
foreach (string deduction in deductions)
{
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[1].Nodes.Add(deduction);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! The housing allowance, mobile phone records wont be static. So I guess I'll have to create a list from the results

Comment: Yes, you already have them just loop for each and add to teeview node. I just made an example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding ordinal values, i would prefer fetching data as XML and then traverse XML, recursively to populate treeview